# SwiftUI Cancel .onDrag

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to cancel a .OnDrag in SwiftUI without lifting the finger from the screen. Is there any way to delete the preview without lifting the finger?

Jakob

Comment: Drag finger out of screen then back, but if you mean programmatically while dragging, then no.